# Remove from first option list if it exsite in the second list using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have two options lists

***First list***

- 0xmohamed
- aaaaaaaaaaa
- test

  ```
             <select id="0" multiple="" size="6">
             <option value="0xmohamed">0xmohamed</option>
             <option value="aaaaaaaaaaa">aaaaaaaaaaa</option>
             <option value="test">test</option></select>
  ```

---

***Second list***

- aaaaaaaaaaa
- test

  ```
             <select id="5" name="ary[]" multiple="" size="6">              
             <option value="aaaaaaaaaaa">aaaaaaaaaaa</option>
             <option value="test">test</option>  </select>
  ```

---

I want to check if value existe in the second list, if yes, remove it from the first list

I tried with this function

```
     var e = document.getElementById('0');
            var f = document.getElementById('5');
            var output = [];
            for(var a= e.options.length-1; a >= 0; a--) {
            output.push(e.options[a].value);

            }
console.log(output);
            for(var b= f.options.length-1; b >= 0; b--) {
            if (output.includes(f.options[b].value)){
                var i=output.indexOf(f.options[b].value);
                console.log(i);

                e.remove(i);

                }}
```

but, it work with one item in the list but not two or more, it remove different option from the first list and i think that's because when an item removed then after second loop, the items in the first list will have different indexes...maybe not sure

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery solution using filter function:

```
$('#0 option').filter(function(){
       return $('#5 option[value='+this.value+']').length > 0
}).remove();
```

```js
$('#0 option').filter(function(){
       return $('#5 option[value='+this.value+']').length > 0
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="0" multiple="" size="6">
           <option value="0xmohamed">0xmohamed</option>
           <option value="aaaaaaaaaaa">aaaaaaaaaaa</option>
           <option value="test">test</option></select>
           
           <select id="5" name="ary[]" multiple="" size="6">              
           <option value="aaaaaaaaaaa">aaaaaaaaaaa</option>
           <option value="test">test</option>  </select>
```

Comment: appreciate your help, it seems better than my solution, i'll accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

i get it work, i changed the first loop to

```
for(var a=0; a <= e.options.length-1; a++)
```

so, the array get filled ascend way, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Please check function `removeOptionIfExits`. I have added explanation in comment lines in the code.

```js
// Remove options from first select which already exist in second select.
function removeOptionIfExits() {
  // retrieve values from the second select
  var values = $("#5 option").toArray().map(x => x.value);
  
  // find all options from first select.
  // filter those options which has value exist in second select
  // loop through it and remove.
  $("#0 option").toArray()
        .filter(x => values.includes(x.value))
        .forEach(x => x.remove());
}

// Call remove function after document ready.
$(document).ready(function(){
  removeOptionIfExits();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="0" multiple="" size="6">
  <option value="0xmohamed">0xmohamed</option>
  <option value="aaaaaaaaaaa">aaaaaaaaaaa</option>
  <option value="test">test</option>
</select>


<select id="5" name="ary[]" multiple="" size="6">
  <option value="aaaaaaaaaaa">aaaaaaaaaaa</option>
  <option value="test">test</option>
</select>
```